# Extracting the text of an element in Selenium Java using css/xpath

Tags: java, selenium

I have this html tree:

```
<div dir="auto" aria-label="Item-Count-0" class="css-901oao">(0)</div>
```

I am trying to extract "0" using xpath/css. I know the css to extract `"Item-Count-0"` should be:

```
@FindBy(css = "div[aria-label='Item-Count-0']")
private WebElement total;
```

But I am not sure how to extract "0" from it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I could answer this very simple question, but I see you don't accepting answers. So, sorry...

Comment: I do accept answers @Prophet I didnt get you

Comment: You did that now...

Comment: I am new to this stack overflow so getting used to it. @Prophet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grab the value of aria-label with getAttribute() method that will retun a string.
Manipulate the string and get the 0 value from it.

```
String ariaLabelValue = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[aria-label='Item-Count-0']")).getAttribute("aria-label");
    String count = ariaLabelValue.split("-")[2];
```

you can further convert this number to int, if required.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the attribute 'Item-Count-0' has 0 which is dynamic. Can you use 'contains' in xpath?

Comment: Agreed! the count will keep on changing from 0 to some value, better to use contains method in xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer parsing to get the value from your site,

```
By cssValue = By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Item-Count-0']");
String elementValue = driver.findElement(cssValue).getText();
int value = Integer.parseInt(elementValue);
```